# Java collection with most performance for lookup table with multiple values per key?

Tags: java, arrays, performance

I am looking to implement a transformation process, based on receiving some value, i want to return one or many instances of a class.

I need to do this at the highest speed possible as it is used as part of a realtime process.

I have a collection of 30,000 classes, each of which with a corresponding key, matching a signal to be received, some classes can be linked to the same key

Which option is the most efficient, or is there another to consider?

- `Multimap`
- `Map<String, ArrayList<Class>>`
- `ArrayList<Class>` and search using predicate?

Comment: HashMap<String, ArrayList<Class>> I would suggest

Comment: Or `Map<String, long>` and `ArrayList<Class>`, to parallelize some of that indirection and remove overheads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your choice should be based on the most frequent operation, in this case search.

`Lists` give you best complexity for insert O(1) and O(n) for search

A `MultiMap<A, B>` associates a key of type A with a value of type Collection

A `Map<A, B>` associates a key of type A with a value of type B.

So, a `MultiMap<Integer, Set<String>>` can be viewed as a

`Map<Integer, Collection<Set<String>>`.

Both give O(1) insert and worst case O(k) k is the longest collection in the values. k is heavily dependent on the quality of the hash function, with good hash function the lookup time can be O(1).

So I would go with either `Map` or `MultiMap`. If you are initializing the structure once and then never inserting new elements then definitely go with `Map`.